# htaccess redirect doesn't render page for 1st time

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting, url-routing

> When the below 2 condition are true, redirect should be done

```html
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} logged=(666);? [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} tenant=((?:444|NOTFOUND));? [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} tenant=((?:555|NOTFOUND));? [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.google.com  [R,L,QSD]
```

```
In Firebug i can able to see the response for the GET operation. But the page is not rendering for the 1st time. **2nd time if i refresh, the redirect is working.** Anyone please help me
```